# Derivation of the Lagrange equation

Tags: physics, euler-lagrange-equation

The physical Lagrange equation is the same as the Euler-Lagrange equation.
My question is why do we use the $$L=T-V$$ as the Lagrangian?

Comment: The full derivation of the Euler-Lagrange equation of some functional $S$ is as follows: Take the derivative of $S$ and set it to zero.

Comment: Totally not what I was asking for. The Euler Lagrange equation is easy to derive, but I asked about the lagrangian equation as known from physics

Comment: Are you asking why $L=T-V$? Where $L$ is the Lagrangian, $T$ is the kinetic energy, and $V$ is the potential energy?

Comment: Yes exactly, that is what I wann to understand

Comment: Crossposted from https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/562499/2451

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Euler-Lagrange equation minimize (or maximize) the integral $$S=\int_{t=a}^{t=b}L(t,q,\dot q) dt$$
The function $L$ then must obey $$\frac d{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial q}$$
The expressions above are for a single variable $q$, but it's easy to extend to multiple variables.

So how is this related to physics? You need to **choose** a function $L$ that has some physical meaning. Note that the function is not unique. If you have a function $L$ that is good, the function $\alpha L+\beta$ will give you the same equations of motion. So what would make a *good* function? In mechanics, we want $L$ to describe the same physics as Newton's laws of motion. We write the second law as $$\frac{d}{dt}(mv)=F$$
Newton's first law can be derived from this, if we set $m=const.$ and $F=0$. If we assume conservative forces (gravity, electromagnetism), then the force can be represented as a gradient of a potential:$$F=-\frac{dV}{dx}$$
So then we write $$\frac d{dt}(mv)=-\frac{dV}{dx}$$
Now we identify $q=x$ and $\dot q=v$. Then $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial v}=mv$$ and $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=-\frac{dV}{dx}$$
One possible solution (if we assume $L$ is a sum of two functions, one that depends only on $x$, the other only on $v$) is $$L=\frac{mv^2}2-V(x)=T-V$$
Once again, this function is a **choice**.

After thinking about some of the comments, I realized that there are some changes to the form of the terms that have some definite physical meaning. For example, I can add a term linear in $v$ to $T$, so it becomes $$T=\frac m2 v^2+\alpha v$$
If you complete the square, one realizes that this is just the kinetic energy in a reference frame moving with a constant velocity. Then obviously one can change $x$ to some $x-x_0$, and the equation of motion does not change. Finally, one can add a constant. But since we have partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $v$, constant means that it does not explicitly depend on those values. But it can depend explicitly on time.

Comment: Ragarding last paragraph, is there a general form to represent all the solutions?

Comment: @GiorgioPastasciutta I'm not sure. But to see how things work in a different setting, just look at the Lagrangian of a charged particle in magnetic field. For example http://insti.physics.sunysb.edu/itp/lectures/01-Fall/PHY505/09c/notes09c.pdf

Comment: What i wanted to ask more precisely was a general solution also including the knowledge of $L$ partial derivatives, such as the ones written in the second-last paragraph

Comment: But thinking about it, if $L$ and $V$ share the same partial derivative wrt $x$ (with opposite sign), then $L=-V(x)+C$, where $C$ is some function not dependent on $x$, while from $L$ partial derivative wrt $v$ we have $C=\frac 1 2 m\,v^2+D$ where $D$ is some function not dependent on $x$ nor on $v$. Eventually general solution is simply the one written plus a constant $D$. So if my reasoning is correct there should be no need to assume $L$ as a sum of two function with one dependence each, because it's the only possibility.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Just note that you chose the form for $T$ (or $\partial L/\partial v$). But, like I've mentioned before, this is not unique choice for the Lagrangian. $L=2T-2V+C$ will also yield the same equations of motion.

Comment: True, so general solution should be $L=k\,(T-V)+C$?

Comment: I think so. But I'm not 100%.

Comment: After some thinking, I realized that I can modify $L$ even more. I'll add it to my answer @GiorgioPastasciutta